# Faithfully insert a string in an area

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to dynamically print a string (which is NOT constant) in a certain area (eg, div `result`). Then I use the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <script>
     var elt = document.createElement("span");
     elt.innerHTML = "=A2<C2";
     document.querySelector("#result").appendChild(elt);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that if the string I want to print contains `<`, it interprets that and does not print `<` faithfully. For example, the above code prints `=A2`.

I see some threads proposing to replace `<` by `<` + space. But I don't like the space inserted. Additionally, I don't know if there are other special characters that will be interpreted.

So does anyone know any general solution to print a string faithfully?

PS: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qemabirixe/2/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute `.textContent` for `.innerHTML`

```
elt.textContent = "=A2<C2";
```

Comment: This is more convenient than my answer, but beware that you need IE9+ for it to work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Then, is it possible to add a newline in the text? `\n` does not seem to work?

Comment: @SoftTimur Original Question does not mention including newline in text. Where should newline be placed within text?

Comment: For example, what if I want to print `=A2<C2 \n =A2>C2"?

Comment: @SoftTimur You can use `css` to set element `white-space` property to `pre` `#result span {white-space:pre;}` which should render newline character at `#result span` selector http://jsbin.com/fuzahegavo/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

Definitely don't insert text with `innerHTML`; only insert HTML that way. Inserting text is a bit more verbose, but not too difficult:

```
elt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("=A2<C2"));
```